# Send Stream/FileStream object from MVC application to WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, stream, filestream

Here is the scenario, where I am stuck:

I want to upload an image/video at client side and send the file information to service so that it can be saved at some server location and the file's metadata can be saved in database.

I read that Stream object cant be send to service with any other parameter, so I created a class which has one stream object and one string attribute to be sent to server and then, I am trying to send the class to service.

But stuck with this error message:

```
There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:stream. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data contract name 'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Can you please fix your quoted text: you've done it as code, it should be just a quote. Also, you'll need to provide more code, e.g. your class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a class object with Stream property using Rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608434/sending-a-class-object-with-stream-property-using-rest)